# What is printed when the following myProgram() method in the SimpleIsland class is executed?

Tags: java, if-statement, operators

While I'm aware of how if/else statements and operators work (there are many posts about it), I seem to have gotten lost within this block of code in particular. I was given the final output (if else if), however I haven't been able to get to that conclusion by simply looking at it and working it out on paper. I'd really appreciate an explanation in plain terms as to what's happening in the code.

```
public class SimpleIsland
{
    public boolean getTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean getFalse()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public static void myProgram()
    {
        if ( getFalse() || getTrue() )
        {
            if ( !getTrue() )
            {
                if ( !getFalse() )
                {
                    System.out.println( "if if if" );
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println( "if if else" );
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if ( !getFalse() )
                {
                    System.out.println( "if else if" );
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println( "if else else" );
                }
            }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "else" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace those functions and nots with the values true and false and things will become clearer.  And please don't ever write code like that.  It'll drive you and whoever has to maintain it crazy.

```
public class SimpleIsland
{
    public boolean getTrue()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public boolean getFalse()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public static void myProgram()
    {
        if ( false || true )
        {
            if ( false )
            {
                if ( true )
                {
                    System.out.println( "if if if" );
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println( "if if else" );
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if ( true )
                {
                    System.out.println( "if else if" );
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println( "if else else" );
                }
            }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "else" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that very much. And this is a practice question given to us to prep for a final exam tomorrow, so I think the professor intended to drive us crazy by writing code like that :/

Answer (score 0):

It will print 'if else if'.  The first if(getFalse() || getTrue()) will return true since we are checking for OR condition.  So after entering the first if, next nested if(!getTrue()) will return false and hence control will move to else condition. Next nested if(!getFalse()) inside else will evaluate to true, thus printing 'if else if'

Comment: Thank you very much. You explained it very clearly. I appreciate that!